# NuShellX code at around A=132

Tags: nuclear-physics, computational-physics, software

I have recently started using the NuShellX code to simulate nuclear excited states. I have been able to get the code to work for the exmaples inlcluded such as Ne22 as well as some higher mass nuclei such as Fe53.

I would like to scale this to up to higher mass nuclei such ad Cd130 In131 and Ag129 around the doubly magic Sn132 nuclei. My problem is when I create the batch file and execute it with these nuclei the code errors out. I cant seem to see any obvious error messages that would give a clue to what is going wrong. I am using these model spaces of jj44 and n50j and their respective interactions. I have attached a screen shot of the login shell (sorry for copying the code directly).

If any one could point me in a direction to help with this that would be very helpful!

[image: Code shell response on executing .bat file]

Cheers

Comment: This is a question more appropriate for softwareengineering.stackexchange.

Comment: @JellyStrawberry no, it definitely isn't. I'd recommend Stack Overflow or (perhaps, I don't know NuShellX good enough) [scicomp.se]. Anyway, the OP needs to include the code and the errors *as text*, not as an image.